# Plots of average values against categories

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I have three variables, two categorical and one continuous. say v1, v2 and v3 respectively. I want to make a plot between v2 and v3 for each categories of v1. Further, in the plot of v2 verses v3 for each category of v1, I have repeated categories of v2. So muliple values of v3 for each category of v2. I actually want to plot the average of v3 for each category of v2. I used lattice xyplot() but it does not provide the required results(it plots all the individuals values of v3 for all categories of v2). Could you please help me in this regard. The data example and code is as follows

```
v1 <- rep(c(2,4,6,8,10), each = 6)  
v2 <- rep(1:3,10)  
v3 <-runif(30,0.01,0.3)
combined_data <- data.frame(v1,v2,v3)  
xyplot(v3 ~ v2|v1, data = combined_data, type = "o")
```

Comment: I would use a `bwplot`. Doesn't give tmeans but rahter the medians if you specify them. If you wnat to see modification to the basic `bwplot` to insert lines at the means, I'm sure that has been asked and answered on SO before.

Comment: could you please mention the code here according to the bwplot?

Answer (score 0):

You generally need to have the as the data-type on the RHS of a bwplot call but the interaction function does provide that facility:

```
bwplot(v3 ~ interaction(v2,v1), data = combined_data,horizontal=FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're going for, so here are three possibilities using `ggplot`.

```
library(ggplot2)
# lines and points; similar to type="o" with xyplot(...)
ggplot(combined_data,aes(x=v2,y=v3))+
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom="line",color="blue",linetype=2)+
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom="point", pch=1,size=3)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=combined_data$v2)+
  facet_grid(~v1)+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

```
# bar plot
ggplot(combined_data,aes(x=factor(v2),y=v3))+
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom="bar",color="grey50",fill="lightgreen")+
  facet_grid(~v1)+
  theme_bw() + labs(x="v2")
```

[image]

```
# boxplot
ggplot(combined_data,aes(x=factor(v2),y=v3))+
  geom_boxplot(color="grey50",fill="lightgreen")+
  facet_grid(~v1)+
  theme_bw() + labs(x="v2")
```

[image]